# Complex Analysis - Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having some trouble with the following question and would appreciate some help:

"The image of the line of equation x+y=1 under the mapping w=1/(z+2+3i), with z=x+iy, is a circle minus a point w_0. Find point w_0."

I have already found the circle, being (x-1/12)^2 + (y+1/12)^2 = 1/72, but wish to be pointed in the right direction about how to find w_0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that $(0,0)$ lies on the circle you have obtained. This point is not in the image because $\frac 1 {z+2-3i}$ cannot be $0$.